# Invoke Super class methods using Reflection

Tags: java

I have 2 classes, say A & B:

```
Class A extends B {
    public void subClassMthd(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

Class B {
    public void printHelloWorld {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Now, I am using reflection to invoke the methods on Class A. I would also like to invoke the printHelloWorld method present in Class B.

I tried using

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.test.ClassA");
Object classAInstance= clazz.newInstance();
Method superClassmthd = classAInstance.getClass()
    .getSuperclass().getMethod("printHelloWorld", null);
superClassmthd.invoke(classAInstance);
```

Also tried as

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.test.ClassA");
Object classAInstance= clazz.newInstance();
Class superClazz = Class.forName(classAInstance.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());
Object superclassInstance = superClazz.newInstance();
Method superClassmthd = superclassInstance.getMethod("printHelloWorld", null);
superClassmthd.invoke(superclassInstance );
```

But none of them work; they throw an [InstantiationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do exactly because the code you have provided doesn't make any sense.  Could you give more details on what you are trying to do?

Comment: An InstantiationException may be thrown when you try to create a new instance of a class, not when invoking regular methods. Are you sure that you're looking at the right spot to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you provide the Exception Stacktrace and the code from method in class B and (if it exist) the overriden and/or overloaded methods from class A? Methods' signatures are sufficient- no need for complete inner method code.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't declare those methods as `protected` or `public` and just call them? Is the source code of the base class inaccessible?

Comment: @PeterLawrey
Updated the question with the code

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis
The source is accessible

Comment: The InstantiationException is probably thrown by `clazz.newInstance();`.

Comment: InstantiationException wraps the true exception which is the cause of your problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
Method mthd = classAInstance.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("XYZ");
mthd.invoke(classAInstance)
```

The difference is using [`getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29), which gets methods of *all* visibilities (`public`, `protected`, package/default and `private`) instead of [`getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29), which only gets methods with `public` visibility.

Comment: This will call classAInstance's XYZ method. I just tested it and it did not call only classAInstance's super.XYZ().

Comment: @user951793 if the super method is overridden by the instance's class (not the situation in this question), then of course the overridden method will be invoked - that behaviour is the core of OOP.

Answer (score 3):

What is the visibility of the methods you want to call (public, private etc).
If you want to see methods which you cannot call directly, you should use getDeclaredMethod().

Also, what the the constructors of your classes like? InstantiationException indicates that you are having trouble getting an instance of class A (or B).

I have the following code and it works:

A.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class A extends B {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A classAInstance = new A();
        Method mthd = classAInstance.getClass().getSuperclass().getMethod("XYZ", null);
        mthd.invoke(classAInstance);
    }

}
```

B.java

```
public class B {

    public void XYZ() {
        System.out.println("done");
    }

}
```